# How to get a file name from a current Class in MQL4 (.mq4)?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

To prevent some boilerplate code, I want to read the file name, of the file a class is executing in.

There is no default **`MQL4`** function available, but it should be possible with a native windows function ( a `GetModuleFileName()` from `kernel32.dll` )

Source - https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

I did read about **`#import`** the `Kernel32.dll`, and steal some functions from there, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#import "kernel32.dll"
  int  GetModuleFileName();
#import
```

It gives me the following error ->

> `2015.01.05 00:15  Cannot find 'GetModuleFileName' in 'kernel32.dll'`

It explains itself, the `getModuleFileName` is not in `kernel32.dll`

Does anyone know how to get the current file name?

Comment: You might have found, that MSDN DLL-interface specifies a few parameters for the `GetModuleFilename( ... )` while your `MQL4` **`#import`** does not. For `DLL`-projects you might want to use **`DependecyWalker`** to inspect DLL content / dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Current filename is read-able via a `__FILE__` macro.

*New-*`MQL4` has a built in support for showing current file name.

With a support for `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__PATH__` et al, one may implement whatever in-vivo / post-mortem code reporting facility suites one's needs.

MetaEditor documentation shows other additional macros `__FUNCSIG__`, `__MQL4BUILD__` and many more.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround..

With the following function

```
typename(this);
```

The ClassName is given.. This gives me enough to work with..

A function that outputs the real 'file-name' is still welcome.